# Can we use variable for a table name in query?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Here in the code I am trying to retrieve information from a database and store it in a table. In query i have used a variable to specify a table, i am doing so because i want to use this single piece of code to retrieve information from various tables based on which table name the variable "a" contain but when i am executing this it's throwing me an exception. please help...

```
MyOleDbConnection.Open();
string a = "login";
string query = string.Format("select Email,Username,PhoneNo,Department from '{1}' where Email='{0}'", editrecordtextBox.Text,a);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, MyOleDbConnection.vcon);
da.Fill(dt);
```

Note- this is just the part of the code, the exception is occuring in this code only.

Comment: Whats the exception message? What database are you using? Probable cause is single quote around table name in your query. Try to remove it.

Comment: i am using ms-access as my database.

Comment: thanks man it worked after removing the quotes....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is in fact working correctly.

First of all, remove your single quotes around the table name. These mark a text, not an identifier or name.

I can imagine that `login` is a reseverd name you cannot use as plain text in your SQL. Depending on the database you can quote your tablename so it is recognizes as a name, not an reserved word.

For SQL-Server it would be done with `[` and `]`:

```
string query = string.Format("select Email,Username,PhoneNo,Department from [{1}] where Email='{0}'", editrecordtextBox.Text,a);
```

If you would give us your database, we could help.

Comment: thanks man, but its working fine after removing the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

the way that tested and Worked is something like Below as you see the Table Name is Variable Form i Make a query with concatenate 3 section together

```
string query = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM M" + TableName.ToString() + " ORDER BY ID 
DESC";
```